# Azure APIM policy checking grater than or equal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

In my poral I have query parameter call "PageSize" and I need to check that user input
condition is grater and need to show message to user

than in my outbound section I put

```
<outbound>
    <choose>
         <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("PageSize")) > = 20">
            <set-status code="205" reason="validation" />
            <set-body template="none">{"Message":"PageSize need to be less than 20"}</set-body>
        </when>
    </choose>
    <base />
</outbound>
```

but when i try to save the portal giving me following error message

```
One or more fields contain incorrect values:
Error in element 'choose' on line 21, column 10: Expression syntax is invalid.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define the complete condition inside `condition="@()`.
This means this has not to be outside of brackets:  `> = 20`

Please do not use a space between `> =`.
Correct: `>=`

The value from the query is `string`. You have to convert this value to an `int`.

Complete fixed outbound policy:

```xml
<outbound>
    <choose>
        <when condition="@(int.Parse(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("PageSize")) >= 20) ">
            <set-status code="205" reason="validation" />
            <set-body template="none">{"Message":"PageSize need to be less than 20"}</set-body>
        </when>
    </choose>
    <base />
</outbound>
```